# Set cookie to show div only once per session

Tags: cookies

I have a div with a Welcome message that shows up before the index page and I want that div to appear only once per session.

How would I set a cookie to show a div only once?

I never used cookies before for something like this, normally I would use Local Storage but this website is visited frequently by older browsers and that's a problem.

Comment: If the site is frequently visited by older browsers why is your question tagged with `html5`?

Comment: @darindimitrov Sorry, I had it as suggested and didn't realize :) I am removing it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the documentation of the [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#Example_.233.3A_Do_something_only_once) and more specifically example 3:

```
if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)someCookieName\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
    alert("Do something here!");
    document.cookie = "someCookieName=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
}
```

In this example the cookie is created with `expires` flag meaning that it will be persistent and survive browser restarts. If you want to perform the action only once per browser session simply remove the `expires` flag when setting the cookie:

```
if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)someCookieName\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
    alert("Do something here!");
    document.cookie = "someCookieName=true; path=/";
}
```

Comment: Well, after reading the documentation I believe this will work so I will be modifying/adding it soon, thanks :)